# issue with apostrophes and double quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm having trouble adding in a variable into the following line of JavaScript:

```
 row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "<div onClick='Myfunction(" +  Password +  ");'></div>"
```

how do I add in the password variable I'm getting confused with apostrophes and double quotes

I think it needs to put the value in-between apostrophes but this clashes with what's already there?

Comment: the variable works if its a number but not when its a string

Comment: the title's got a problem if its got a space between `java` and `script`.

Comment: you can try escape quotes with backslashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
 var Password ='sample';

 document.getElementById("id1").value= '<div onClick="Myfunction(\'' +  Password +  '\');"></div>';

 alert(document.getElementById("id1").value);
```

This is called Escaping. Use backslash() for the character which you want to escape.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home in an hour, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  `row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "<div onClick=Myfunction('" +  Password +  "');></div>"`

Comment: I did when you run it, it displays as follows: " passwordVal' instead of 'passwordVal'

Comment: Is it between a double quote and a single quote?

Comment: it puts in a double quote and then a space and then the password, its weird... maybe I'm doing something wrong. sorry

Comment: Why you don't try `&` instead of `+`? I think it's `vb.net` right?

Answer (score 1):

you can try escape quotes with backslashes like this

```
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "<div onClick='Myfunction(\"" +  Password +  "\");'></div>"
```

Comment: I'll try this when I get home in an hour, thanks for the answer

Comment: yep this one worked thanks mate, sorry i can only mark one answer at a time